# Unsafe redirect to URL

Tags: django

i'm create a class views on django, but get this error:

```
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'products'
```

this is my code on the views:

```
class CreateProduct(CreateView):

    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = "administrador/create_product.html"
    success_url = "products:admin_productos"
```

this is my urls:

```
url(r'^create_product$', CreateProduct.as_view(), name="create_product"),
```

i dont know why get this error..please some one idea..!!

thanks..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Success_url` runs `get_success_url` method inside of `CreateView` and this method should return url via reverse lookup. This can be achieved by passing appropriate view to the `reverse()`.

```
success_url = reverse('products:admin_productos')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your success URL is invalid - you need to pass an actual URL, not the name of one - i.e, you need to `reverse` that name first. Change it to:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CreateProduct(CreateView):
    
    success_url = reverse_lazy("products:admin_productos")
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) for why `reverse_lazy()` is appropriate here instead of `reverse()`:

> It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded. Some common cases where this function is necessary are:
>
> - providing a reversed URL as the url attribute of a generic class-based view.